Is sky still blue when the line-of-sight is perpendicular to the sunlight ray?
We model molecules in the atmosphere, excited by sunlight, as tiny dipoles, which radiate as ~ $\omega^4 \sin^2 \theta$, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\theta$ is the angle between line-of-sight and the dipole direction. This means that when $\theta=0$, or when the line-of-sight is perpendicular to the ray, no radiation is emitted at that angle. Does that mean the sky looks clear if we look at the right angle?

You can answer this without mathematics, by observation. Of course, then, you should want to repair your mathematical model to match.

No it doesn't because sunlight that enters the atmosphere is unpolarised. Thus it effectively consists of a mixture of two perpendicular polarisation states of equal amplitude with random phases between them.
That means that even if $\theta=0$ for the dipole oscillations induced by one of the two polarisation states, $\theta \neq 0$ for the oscillations induced by the perpendicular polarisation state. In your scenario where there is a right angle between the incoming sunlight and the scattering direction, then one of the incoming polarisations makes a full contribution to the scattered light whilst the other is absent - i.e. linearly polarised scattered light.
Of course, the atmosphere has a finite thickness, allows multiple scattering, and also contains particulates with different scattering properties, and so perfect linear polarisation is not achieved in practice.

How is the thickness of the atmosphere related to the achievability of the 90° scattering angle? Assuming a point-like sun shining from infinity at a 45° elevation, we can find a 90° scattering angle from the opposite azimuth at the same elevation. The 0.5° width of our Sun and its 1AU distance wouldn't contribute much of a difference. (Though higher-order scattering will not allow the radiance to be zero in any direction, even if sunlight were polarized and the Sun were at infinity and point-like.)

@Ruslan - agreed.

First of all, using the symbol $\theta$ for the angle between the line of sight and the direction of polarization is potentially misleading here as this symbol is normally used for the scattering angle. So let me use $\gamma$ for this angle here instead.
With this understanding, the factor $\sin^2\gamma$ you mentioned gives the intensity variation with $\gamma$ for incoming polarized light. If the incoming light is unpolarized however (like in the case of the Sun), the intensity as function of the scattering angle $\theta$ is
$$I \propto 1+\cos^2 \theta $$
so at a right angle to the incoming radiation ($\theta=90^o$), the intensity is half that in the forward or backward direction.
See the following diagram for an illustration

The torus shaped figure at the top gives the intensity distribution for a vertical polarization vector $\vec{E}$ ($\vec{\Omega}$ is the propagation direction of the incoming light), the middle figure applies for a horizontal polarization vector, and the bottom figure for unpolarized light. The latter is essentially obtained by rotating the torus for a full circle around the direction of propagation of the incoming light.
(the figure was taken from https://www.patarnott.com/atms749/pdf/ch12PettyScattering.pdf which gives a detailed theoretical treatment of Rayleigh scattering (as well as other types of scattering)).

Thank you so much! This is very intuitive.
